# merge dates when dates following previous record with zero or one day gap

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I want to merge multiple records into single when start date follows end date or start date equals to end date in SQL Server based on ID, also get MAX(ID2) within that group

Below is the sample input & output. Also added SQL code for input table:

```
create table #T (ID1 INT, ID2 INT, StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE)

insert into #T values
(100, 764286, '2019-05-01', '2019-05-31'),
(100, 764287, '2019-06-01', '2019-06-30'),
(100, 764288, '2019-07-10', '2019-07-31'),
(101, 764289, '2020-02-01', '2020-02-29'),
(101, 764290, '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31'),
(102, 764291, '2021-10-01', '2021-10-31'),
(102, 764292, '2021-11-01', '2021-11-30'),
(102, 764293, '2021-11-30', '2021-12-31'),
(103, 764294, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31');
```

[image: Sample input & output]

Here is the script, that I tried, but it is not giving the results I am expecting for ID 100, it shouldn't merge all records related to ID 100

```
select m.ID1,
       NewID2  AS ID2,
       m.StartDate,
       lead(dateadd(day, -1, StartDate), 1, MaxEndDate) over (partition by ID1 order by StartDate) as EndDate
from (select *,
             lag(StartDate) over (partition by ID1 order by StartDate) as S1,
             lag(StartDate) over (partition by ID1 order by StartDate) as S2,
             max(EndDate) over (partition by ID1) as MaxEndDate,
             max(ID2) over (partition by ID1) as NewID2
      from #T
     ) m
where S2 is null or S1 <> S2;
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 5):

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a92cd34e66cfcb3934c973e7a335b19)

```
select id1, max(id2) as id2, min(startdate) as startdate, max(enddate) as enddate
from
(
  select *, sum(addone) over(partition by id1 order by startdate,enddate,id2 rows unbounded preceding) as grp
  from
  ( 
    select *, 
      case when startdate <= dateadd(day, 1, max(enddate) over(partition by id1 order by startdate,enddate,id2 rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding))
           then 0 
           else 1 
      end as addone
    from #T
   ) as r
) as g
group by id1, grp
order by id1, startdate ;
```