# Given 3 rows, If the difference between the endtime and startime of 2 different rows is less than 5, merge them

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Given 3 rows, If the difference between the endtime and startime of 2 different rows is less than 5, I want to merge them.

So Given:

[image]

I want to get:

```
a   | b  | StartTime               | EndTime

161 | 25 | 2020-12-07 00:00:00.000 | 2021-09-03 00:00:00.000
```

Because the difference between 1st row endtime and 2nd row starttime is < 5 so they merged and then it finally merged with the 3rd row.

How can we achieve this in SQL? Thanks :)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: difference between the endtime and startime of 2 different rows is less than 5 **what? Days? Hours? Years?**

Comment: Given you seem to want an iterative approach, you might start by using a gaps-and-islands approach to identify any gaps 5 or greater (of whatever units you are using), which will then give you the islands which you can consolidate into 1 row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge dates when dates following previous record with zero or one day gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70604632/merge-dates-when-dates-following-previous-record-with-zero-or-one-day-gap)